# How to change angular $state if i have response from server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If i rendered data in response from server i want to change state to `modeler` but that is not happening with below code. is there any other way to change angular $state ?

ctrl.js

```
function addUser(newUser) {
    $log.info('addUser', newUser);
    UserService.addUser(newUser)
        .then(function(resp) {
            console.log('Resp', resp.data);
            if (resp.data) {
                $state.go('modeler');
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            $log.info(err);
            toastr.error('Failed to add user (' + newUser._id + ')');
        });
}
```

app.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider, PAGE_ACCESS) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('modeler', {
        url: '/modeler',
        templateUrl: 'app/modeler/modeler.html',
        controller: 'ModelerCtrl',
        data: {
          authorizedRoles: PAGE_ACCESS.modeler
        },
        resolve: {
          auth: function resolveAuthentication(AuthResolver) {
            return AuthResolver.resolve(PAGE_ACCESS.modeler);
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Basicly here you're saying that you want to render the modeler view only if the returned resp.data is true, right?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: What _is_ happening? Are you getting any response from the server? What is it?

Comment: Have you injected `$state` at the start of your controller? Can you show more of your controller?

Comment: The problem is that resp.data value isn't what he is expecting, as it seems.

Comment: my concern is not what is in the resp.data if its true i want to change or may be refresh current $state.

Comment: yes $state is injected

Comment: Are you sure that the `$state.go` code was executed? Are you sure the `auth` resolver function returns a fulfilled promise? If the `auth` function had an error, the state will fail to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would try debugging the resp.data variable to discover what it contains, the problem you're having is that you're expecting a "true" from resp.data, but the value is different.

Maybe the value you're expecting is located inside the object resp.data.status or another value like that, just debugg and explore a little.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah i just want to change $state if resp is true thats all i wanted to do for now.

Comment: Do you know what is the expected response output? You can play with that... f.e: If you're expecting a string and the resp.data equals null, definitely you don't want to render the modeler view, but if the value typeof equals "string", you're close to the desired response.